# Синтез речи через google

Tags: google-translate, java

Здравствуйте. Хочу реализовать произношение текста в моей программе с помощью гугл, у меня есть ссылка типа

```
https://translate.google.ru/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=**привет**&tl=ru&total=1&idx=0&textlen=6&client=t
```

где слово **привет** - это фраза, которую надо произнести. В ответ на этот запрос возвращается звуковой файл в формате `audio/mpeg`. Как мне это реализовать на Java?

Заранее большое спасибо!